# Compare two week numbers from different years in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some calculations that are strongly dependent on "this week", "next week", etc.

Let's say I have a date (Column A). I can use `WEEKNUM((A1), 2)` in Column B to get the week number.

In Column C, I can enter this formula to check if the event is this week or next week.

```
=IF(B1=WEEKNUM((TODAY()),2),"this week",IF(B1=WEEKNUM((TODAY()+7),2),"next week","way in the future"))
```

[image]

This all works great until I have events that cross into next year. So December 31, 2019, will be week 53 and December 31, 2020, will be week 53.

This is an issue because I need a way to account that December 31, 2020 happens later than December 31, 2019.
How do I account for change in years in this formula?

Update:
Adding YEAR as an additional condition will allow me to compare if the date HAS a different year but it still won't let me dynamically calculate, this week, next week.

In this second example, I set two dates and set my computer time as December 31 2019. The result is that instead of reporting 1/1/2020 as "next week" the formula returns "way in the future" which is incorrect.

Is there basically a way to subtract or add weeks using serial week number since epoch time?

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57982487/edit) to post some sample data? As it is, you say there is a date in column `A`, but in your formula it looks like you expect column `A` to have the week numbers. Which one is it?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad. Sorry, just included an image with an example and fixed the typo.

Comment: use AND to test the year also: `AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)=B1,YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(A1))`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner

Comment: @ScottCraner. If you don't mind, please take a look at the update.

Comment: You need to put the same test for year in the future date also.

Comment: @ScottCraner  This creates unnecessary checks, in addition, to already multiple checks that I'm performing. In your example I will not be able to identify the difference if it's less than current year or more than current year so basically every check I do will have to be checked 3 times(and previous year, and this year, and next year). There's gotta be a more reasonable way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, I think I figured it out. Instead of comparing week numbers, we extract the Monday of each week and perform a similar comparison like before. Except we now have the entire date instead of just the week number.

=IF(A2-MOD(A2-2,7)=TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-2,7),"this week",IF(A2-MOD(A2-2,7)=TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-2,7)+7,"next week","way in the future"))